# Read List of URLs to obtain informations

Tags: linux, bash, perl

Can you complete this Perl/bash script for a url and for a list of urls and tell me how to write several regex in the same script?

```
    wget -Otest.html https://www.cormes.de/impressum

    perl -nE 'if (/\bmailto:([\w\.]+\@[\w\.]+)/) { say $1 
    }'test.html

    perl -nE 'if (/Straße: \[A-Za-z] [0-9]/) {say 
    $1}'test.html

    perl -nE 'if ( /PLZ und Ort: \ [0-9] {5} - [A-Za-z]) 
    /{say $1}'test.html 

    perl -nE 'if (/FirstName and LastName: \[A-Za-z] [A-Za- 
    z])/{say $1}'test.html

    perl -nE'if( 's|\([0-9]{2}\)-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9] 
    {2}-[0-9]{2}|##-###-###-##-##|g')
```

To extract an email, this regex works well.
The other regex are validated by regex 101.
I have the link to get the CEO's first and last name but don't know which tool allows you to decode it to use it in the script.
[https://idowapro.de/impressum/#:~:text=Gesch%C3%A4ftsf%C3%BChrer%3A%20Lutz%20Teubert](https://idowapro.de/impressum/#:%7E:text=Gesch%C3%A4ftsf%C3%BChrer%3A%20Lutz%20Teubert)
How is this script written to accumulate several regexes for a single url and for a list of urls?

Comment: The ' at each line is an error and should be deleted. Yes I want to call perl just once and have it run several tests on a downloaded file.

Comment: Thank you nathalie malapelle. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/687279/edit) to present the code correctly, so that we are answering the right question.

Comment: I corrected the script and reedited

Comment: Every single line (except the `wget`) has at least one error on it. If you have a working script please copy and paste it. Accurately